# Select features of layer which is not on top

Tags: openlayers

I have a map with 3 layers: 1 base layer, 1 overlay and 1 WFS layer.
I load them like this:

```
map.addLayers([baseLayer, wfsLayer, overlayLayer]);
```

When an user clicks on the map it should select the feature on the WFS layer.
So I have added the select control after calling map.addLayers:

```
  selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
      [wfsLayer],
      {
          clickout: true, toggle: false,
          multiple: false, hover: false
      }
  );
  map.addControl(selectControl);
  selectControl.activate();
```

This works great, my features get selected when clicked.

But my overlay layer is beneath the WFS layer and I want it to be on top.
The overlay layer is a non-filled polygon layer.
So I added

```
map.setLayerZIndex(overlayLayer, map.Z_INDEX_BASE[ "Feature" ]+10);
```

after map.addLayers.
This looks OK. My overlay layer is now above my WFS layer.
But when I now click on the map, nothing gets selected.

Most likely I'm not doing it right. How can I make my overlay layer on top and my WFS layer selectable?

[EDIT]

As mentioned by Christophe I tried

```
  selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature( 
      [wfsLayer, overlayLayer], 
      { 
        clickout: true, toggle: false, 
        multiple: false, hover: false
      }
  );
```

But that resulted in an OL Error, probably because the overlay layer is a WMS layer.

[EDIT #2]

I've reposted this question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59619/select-features-of-layer-which-is-not-on-top-in-openlayers

Comment: Try passing multiple layers to the SelectFeature constructor: `[wfsLayer, overlayLayer]`

Comment: Thanks Christophe. I did try that but then I get this error:
     TypeError: a.renderer is undefined

The overlayLayer is a GWC layer (using GeoServer)

Comment: Maybe try the GIS stackexchange forums, I never used a GWC layer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you are using the wrong method to change your layer order.

I would suggest trying

```
var wfsLayer = map.getLayersByName('WFS_Layer_Name')[0];
map.raiseLayer(wfsLayer, map.layers.length);
```

If you only have one other layer this should bring your wfs layer to the top and allow your control to work correctly.

If you have more than one other layer or you wish to set a specific index you could try

```
var wfsLayer = map.getLayersByName('WFS_Layer_Name')[0];
map.setLayerIndex(wfsLayer, 99);
```

Please note your select control constructor should only list your wfs layer if that is the only layer you want to select from.